# Some claims about spectra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

I see the following equalities used sometimes, but couldn't find proofs. How is it done?

$$\overline{Ran(L-\lambda\mathbb{1})}^{\perp}=ker(L^*-\overline{\lambda}\mathbb{1})$$
and
$$\lambda\in\sigma_p(L)\implies\overline{\sigma_p(L^*)\cup\sigma_r(L^*)}$$

I couldn't find a rigorous set of assumptions either, so I guess we are talking densely defined bounded operators on Hilbert spaces, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Your second statement appears incomplete

Comment: That's possible. I got it from here: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m511/spectralExamples.pdf, Example 2, 'Other spectrum of R'.

Comment: @SimonS can you tell me what you think is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is a standard result (easy to prove also!) available in most books on operator theory for eg: Proposition 4.6 in Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory by R.G. Douglas, 2nd edition states it as follows

> If   $T$  is an operator on the Hilbert space $H$, then $ker T = (ran T^*)^\perp  $ and $(ran T)^\perp = ker T^*$

This proposition along with the result

> If $M$ is a subset of a Hilbert Space then $M^\perp = {\overline M}^\perp $

which is again easy to prove gives answer to your first part  (Take $T = L-\lambda 1$).

For the second part, let $H$ be the underlying Hilbert space. The correct statement is
$\lambda \in \sigma_p (L) \Rightarrow \overline \lambda \in \sigma_r(L^*) \cup \sigma_p(L^*)$

$Proof: $ First of all note that

$\sigma (L)= \sigma_p(L) \cup\sigma_c(L) \cup \sigma_r (L)$

for reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)

Observe that  if $\lambda \in \sigma (L)$ then $ \overline \lambda \in \sigma(L^*)$. Also if $\lambda \in \sigma_p (L)$ then there exists a non zero $x\in H $ such that 
$ (L-\lambda) x = 0 $ then

$\forall y \in H, $

$ \langle(L-\lambda) x , y  \rangle = 0  \Rightarrow \langle x ,(L^*-\overline\lambda) y  \rangle = 0 $

If $Ran (L^*-\overline \lambda)  $ is dense then $x$ must be zero which is a contradiction. Therefore, $\overline \lambda \notin \sigma_c(L^*) \Rightarrow \overline \lambda \in \sigma_r(L^*) \cup \sigma_p(L^*)$ (since we already know that $\overline \lambda \in \sigma(L^*)$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I proved the second part on my own in a slightly different manner, by using that $dom(A) \subset dom(A^{**})$ for a densely defined operator. What I do not understand in your proof is why you assume that your $y$ lies in $H$. The expression after the implication arrow might not be defined in this case right? Wouldn't you have to constrain y to the domain of A* for that. Also how does one proof that $\sigma(L)=\sigma(L^*)$? I don't see where one needs this but it seems interesting. Also: Could you give me a hint at how to prove $(M^\perp)^\perp=M$ for M subspace of H

Comment: Proved the $(M^\perp)^\perp=\overline{M}$ claim.

Comment: Well, I was talking about bounded( everywhere defined and continuous) operators only where the problem of domain does not arise. $\sigma (L) = \overline{\sigma(L^*)}$ is my claim. This is true because if $L- \lambda 1$ is invertible if and only if $(L- \lambda 1)^* = L^*- \overline \lambda 1$ is invertible and thus $\lambda \notin \sigma (L)$ if and only if $\overline \lambda \notin \sigma (L^*)$

Comment: Is there a short proof for invertibility of the adjoint or would this require some work?

Comment: $(L^*)^{-1} = (L^{-1})^*$ write it down  algebraically and u are done

Comment: Well. I see that for any given x one gets $<(L^{-1})^*L^*x,x>=<x,x>$ but this doesn't prove that $(L^{-1})^*L^*x=x$ does it. I don't know what else to do with $(L^{-1})^*L^*x$ at the moment.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i was away from computer. Notice that $(L^{-1})*L^* = (LL^{-1})^* = I$ similarly $L^*(L^{-1})* = (L^{-1}L)^* = I $ I have used the formula $(AB)^* = B^*A^*$